# Why does this error show up in this case but not the other?

Tags: python

```
def biggestWithPos(A):
    answer = 0
    for i in A:
        if i > answer:
            answer = i
    return (answer)
```

Why is it that when I change `answer = i` to `answer = A[i]` I get the error: `list index out of range`?

Comment: Can you send part of the code where you call the function?

Comment: Because i is not the index, it is the actual value in the array.

Comment: Right.  IF you wanted to use `A[i]`, your for loop would be `for i in range(len(A)):`, but the way you have it is better.  Well, "better" would be replacing the whole function with `return max(A)`.

Answer (score 1):

In this:

```
for i in A:
```

`i` is not the *index* but rather the *element* in `A`, which is presumably a list.

If `A` were `[4, 5, 6]`, then doing this you'd be trying to access `A[4]` on the first iteration, which is an out of range index.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, when you are inside a for loop like `for i in A`, i is not the index of the iterator you’re iterating over: i is the current element of the iterator A.
Let’s see what that means with an example:

```
A = [7, 4, 3, 2]
for i in A:
    print(i)
```

This code will print 7 4 3 2 (each one on a new line) and not 0 1 2 3 since i in the loop stands for the current element of the iterator and not the index.
If you tried printing `A[i]`, you would get the same error you described in your answer since, again, 7 (i.e. the value of i during the first iteration) is not the index of the current iteration but the element you are currently iterating over.

Comment: This answer would be better if it explicitly described how using `7` as an index in `A[i]` generates the error the OP saw.